# Many to Many (Students , classes example) Datagrid xaml binding

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, xaml, data-binding

I have a WPF / entity framework application,
my model have student , class entities 
there is a many to many association/relation between student and class (student can have many classes and class have many students )

student [ Id ,Name , Classes(Navigation property) ]
classes [ Id ,Title, Students(Navigation property ]

in this case the entity framework don't show the join/relation table.

i have a 2 DataGirds as master details, student grid is the master and classes is details

how can i set the binding to classes gird (the details gird) so i can add and remove classes to the selected student?

what i want is to select a student from the master grid and add or remove his classes

this is my classes gird

```
<DataGrid x:Name="classesDataGrid"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                      Height="200"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource studentClassesViewSource}}"
                      RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
                      Width="380">
                <DataGrid.Columns>


                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Class Name From Combo"
                                            Width="*"

                                            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource classViewSource}}" 
                                            DisplayMemberPath="Name"

                                            SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Students}" 

                                            />
                    <!--<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="durationColumn"
                                        Binding="{Binding Duration}"
                                        Header="Duration"
                                        Width="SizeToHeader" />-->

                </DataGrid.Columns>
```

This scenario works fine when the relation is one to many but i couldn't make it work for many to many relations .

More on this post 
[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/74ca2429-cb22-4b24-ae22-01a842b7d8c2/many-to-many-students-classes-example-datagridcomboboxcolumn-binding-problem)

Comment: Help please  !! Any One ???

Comment: Few years later I also face this problem +1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your problem correctly:
You wanna know how to solve that master detail binding issue in xaml?

If you have a Student with a classes collection as a navigation property you could simply use one grid for students, eg:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="masterGrid"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Students}" />
```

and another one for the details (your classes - or vice versa, doesn't matter):
In this case I would suggest you an element name binding

```
<DataGrid x:Name="detailsGrid"
          DataContext="{Binding ElementName=masterGrid, Path=SelectedItem}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Classes}" />
```

Hope that helped (at least for the initial ignition)...

Comment: sorry for late reply , my problem is how to add items to details grid?, this post describe it [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/74ca2429-cb22-4b24-ae22-01a842b7d8c2/many-to-many-students-classes-example-datagridcomboboxcolumn-binding-problem)

Comment: Do you really want to navigate from Students to Classes and vice versa? Isn't it enough to have students with classes (remove students collection from classes)?